# How to add a PostgreSQL 10 identity column to an existing table?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, identity, postgresql-10

I'm reading about the new [Postgres 10 identity column](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/), and saw how it is used to replace `SERIAL` columns when `CREATE TABLE`.

Is it also possible to add an identity column to an existing table?

For example, with the old `SERIAL` columns, I can do:

```
ALTER TABLE sourceTable ADD  COLUMN ogc_fid SERIAL;
```

With the identity columns, is there an equivalent of above? I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE sourceTable ADD  COLUMN ogc_fid GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;
```

But got an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BY" LINE 1: ...R TABLE sourceTable
>   ADD  COLUMN ogc_fid GENERATED BY DEFAULT

I'm thinking about replacing the `SERIAL` columns with `IDENTITY` columns in my scripts, and just wanted to check if this is feasible.

Comment: The link you have provided shows how to upgrade. Just scroll down till **Upgrading**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to declare the type of the column, too (`INT` or `BIGINT` or 
`SMALLINT`):

```
ALTER TABLE sourceTable 
    ADD COLUMN ogc_fid int                -- int or bigint or smallint
        GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;
```

Also be sure to use the latest point release. As the `IDENTITY` has only been recently added, there were bugs affecting this particular command before Postgres 10.2. See: 
[How to add a PostgreSQL 10 identity column to an existing table with rows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/200156/3684)

Comment: @tinlyx: And be sure to use the latest point release. There were bugs affecting this particular command before Postgres 10.2. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/200156/3684

Comment: Thnx @ErwinBrandstetter, updated the answer.